# How does /etc/fstab backup data?

Tags: backup, fstab

I was reading about `/etc/fstab` file, and found out that this file can `dump` data, and when searched for it, I understood that `dump` means `backup`.

```
# <file system>                 <dir>       <type>    <options>     <dump> <pass>
UUID=6a454a-bfd1-38989910eccd    /           ext4      defaults       1      1
```

1. I want to know what it backup? The whole filesystem?
2. where is the backup file?
3. When does it work? On every boot?
4. Does it need an external program called `dump`?

**Edit:**
My question is not about the `backup methods`. I just want to know the story behind this `dump` column of the `fstab` file.

Comment: https://superuser.com/a/247527/475611

Comment: Thank you, but I've read that before, it helped me to ask these questions. @Pilot6

Comment: It is not used any more.

Comment: So people these days backup their data just using copy/paste? @Pilot6

Comment: There is a ton of backup methods, but this one is obsolete,

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Comparison of backup tools](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2596/comparison-of-backup-tools)

Comment: Forget about `dump`ing your file systems to tape: that is just *very ancient* technology (possible but not advised as a backup system any more). Have a look at the duplicate instead.

Comment: Thank you very much, but my question is not about the "backup tools". I just wanted to know "the history of this column in `fstab`" and "How did it work in past?" . @Fabby

Comment: [Reading the manual](https://linux.die.net/man/8/dump) is the best answer then as no one uses it any more. You'd have to find a greybeard that was a SysAdmin 30 years ago...  **;-)**  (I was one 20 years ago and we used `rsync` already back then...)

Answer (score 1):

From `man fstab`:

```
   The  fifth  field,  (fs_freq),  is  used  for  these filesystems by the
   dump(8) command to determine which filesystems need to be  dumped.   If
   the  fifth  field  is not present, a value of zero is returned and dump
   will assume that the filesystem does not need to be dumped.
```

Nothing is dumped/backedup automatically.

Comment: How does `dump` command work? I have never heard of it.

Comment: It doesn't work, because dump is not installed in Ubuntu.

Comment: Any backup application could look at that fstab field to manage backup frequency or they can have another way to keep track of that. The format of /etc/fstab goes way back to the last century, and may have become redundant by now.

Comment: https://linux.die.net/man/8/dump

Comment: It's taken me ages to understand this. I finally realise that the "dump" value is used only when you use `dump -w` or `dump -W`. Even then, `dump` uses this only to display information about the dumps (backups) and not to do anything about it. Please correct me if I've misunderstood! (In any case, I rather suspect that the more modern backup systems `rsync`, `rdiff-backup` and `rclone` would be better substitutes.)